# Dax formula won't ignore the last dropdown filter in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am working on a report in Power BI where I have 4 filters to sort the data, and for the report to function properly, the revenue formula needs to ignore the last filter (indicator) so that I can make a comparison. I have tried

```
Profit =
CALCULATE (
    [Caravan] + [PKW] + betrag[sleistung] + betrag[smaterial] + betrag[sumsatz],
    ALL ( table[indicator] )
)
```

But it is not working. Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For your calculation to ignore the filter completely, the ALL function has to be used in each individual measure as well. That is, all the following measures should be rewritten to ignore the filter:

- Caravan
- PKW
- sleistung
- smaterial
- sumsatz

Once the filter is excluded in all these measures, the calculation should work as expected. Hope this helps.